# Unusual amount of data pulled into the driver when calling dataframe.collect in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my spark code, I am collecting a small object on the driver from a Dataframe. I see the following error message on the console. I am calling `dataframe.take(1)` in my program.

```
Total size of serialized results of 13 tasks (1827.6 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
```

This know that this can be resolved by setting `spark.driver.maxResultSize` param. But my question is, Why is so much of data being pulled into the driver when the object that I am collecting is less than an MB in size. Is it the case that all the objects are first serialized and pulled into the driver and then the driver selects one of them (`take(1)`) for the output.

Answer (score -2):

From the above question it seems like you would like to take 1 row from your dataframe which can be acheived using below code.

```
df.take(1)
```

However, When you will perform `df.take(1).collect()` in that case collect will be applied on the result of `take(1)` which is another collection in scala or python (depending on which language you are using.)

Also, why you would like to perform collect on take(1)?

Regards,

Neeraj